# How to disable a UIBarButton when two textfields are empty while they are changing in iOS - Swift 3

Tags: swift3, uitextfielddelegate

I want to disable the bar button item if two textfields are empty.
The two textfields are textField and textFieldNbrSpans.

For just one textfield, I used the following code, and it worked fine:

```
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let oldText: NSString = textField.text! as NSString
    let newText: NSString = oldText.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string) as NSString

    if (newText.length > 0) {

        doneBarButton.isEnabled = (newText.length > 0)
        let tintColor = UIColor(red: 48/255.0, green: 116/255.0, blue: 154/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        let attrs = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: tintColor, NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "Cochin-Italic", size: 16)!]
        doneBarButton.setTitleTextAttributes(attrs, for: .normal)

    } else {

        let tintColor = UIColor(red: 48/255.0, green: 116/255.0, blue: 154/255.0, alpha: 0.2)
        let attrs = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: tintColor, NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "Cochin-Italic", size: 16)!]
        doneBarButton.setTitleTextAttributes(attrs, for: .normal)
        doneBarButton.isEnabled = false

    }
```

When I tried to add another textfield to above code, it gave error:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let oldText: NSString = textField.text! as NSString
    let newText: NSString = oldText.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string) as NSString

    let oldTextSpan: NSString = textFieldNbrSpans.text! as NSString
    let newTextSpan: NSString = oldTextSpan.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string) as NSString

    if (newText.length > 0 && newTextSpan.length > 0) {

        doneBarButton.isEnabled = (newText.length > 0 && newTextSpan.length > 0)
        let tintColor = UIColor(red: 48/255.0, green: 116/255.0, blue: 154/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        let attrs = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: tintColor, NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "Cochin-Italic", size: 16)!]
        doneBarButton.setTitleTextAttributes(attrs, for: .normal)

    } else {

        let tintColor = UIColor(red: 48/255.0, green: 116/255.0, blue: 154/255.0, alpha: 0.2)
        let attrs = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: tintColor, NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "Cochin-Italic", size: 16)!]
        doneBarButton.setTitleTextAttributes(attrs, for: .normal)
        doneBarButton.isEnabled = false

    }
```

Is there a way to improve the code above in a way to have the bar button disabled in case the 2 textfields `textfield` & `textfieldNbrSpan` are empty?

Comment: what is the error you got

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can do it.

- You should have two `global` variables.
- And you should define `tags` to your both `text fields`.to do that, select your `first textfield` and go to `attribute inspector` then under the `view section` select the `Tag` as `0` for `first text field` and , `1` for `second textfield`. and `drag` and enable `delegates` for your textfields.(assume that your know these).
- create and `IBOutlet` for your `navigation bar button`.

Then your `view controller should look like. below.`

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mybutton: UIBarButtonItem! // outlet for your button



    var textOne : NSString! = "" // global variable one to hold first text field value
    var textTwo : NSString! = "" // global variable two to hold second text field value

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        mybutton.isEnabled = false // first your button should disabled
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool { // delegate method

        if textField.tag == 0 { // get the first text field valued when user change the first text field
            textOne = (textField.text ?? "") as NSString
            textOne = textOne.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string) as NSString!
        }
        else { // get the second text field value, when user change it
            textTwo = (textField.text ?? "") as NSString
            textTwo = textTwo.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string) as NSString!
        }


        // check the two variables and do the enable and disable things. do your button styles also here.
        if textOne != "" && textTwo != "" {
            mybutton.isEnabled = true
        }
        else {
            mybutton.isEnabled = false
        }

        return true

    }


}
```

**Note : I didn't implement any styles for button, just wanted to show you how to do it. hope this will help to you. good luck**